# Retornar cadena de .done s en una respuesta Ajax de Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, promesas, asincronismo

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
function GET_URLAsync(strUrl, aParm) {

    var response = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Paginas/" + strUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(aParm),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
    });
    response.always(function (data) {
        //replace to complete
    });
    response.done(function (data) {//replace to success
        var registros = data.d;
        if ($.type(registros) != "null") {
            //dataReturn = registros;
            return registros
        } else {
            console.log("Data NULL del servidor ");
            return [];
        }
    });
    response.then(function (data) {
        //Incorporates the functionality of the .done() and .fail() methods
    });
    response.fail(function (data) { //replace to error
        // handle request failures
        swal("Error petición GET");
    });
    return response;
}
```

Es una funcion estandar que hace llamadas al servidor. la forma como la utilizo es la siguiente.

```
    //Llamada al servidor de manera Asincrona. :D
    GET_URLAsync(strUrl, aParm).done(function (periodos) {
        console.log(periodos)
        f_LlenarListaPeriodosAlumnos(periodos);
    });
```

El problema es que al hacer `console.log(periodos)`. me sale un objeto, y para recuperar mi lista tengo que poner nuevamente el `.d`(`periodos.d`).

Como podría hacer para que el `.done` anterior de la función estándar me retorne la la lista limpia y ya no tenga que poner `.d`. Algo asi como:

```
$.ajax({})
.done(function(){
return "hola "
})
.done(function(dataHola){
return dataHola+" Vitmar"
})
.done(function (dataHolaVitmar){
console.log(dataHolaVitmar)
});
```

Sera posible? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `done` siempre recibe como argumento el objeto recibido en la respuesta AJAX.

Pero puedes usar un `then` antes del done para filtrar este valor, quedandote solo con la propiedad `.d` si es lo que necesitas:

```
GET_URLAsync(strUrl, aParm)
    .then(function(periodos) {
        return periodos.d;
    })
    .done(function (d) {

    });
```

Comment: Probé la solución que mencionas y no funciona.

Comment: en vez de "no funciona" es mejor si pones el motivo... ¿sale un error? ¿no hacel lo esperado? etc

Comment: Sigue saliendo lo mismo `data.d`

Comment: Aquí tienes una prueba de que funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/6ougkcdp/

Comment: Aya ya entendí, era que en mi funcion `GET_URLAsync` yo estaba retornando el objeto `response` en lugar del `response.then()`. Gracias...